# Sign out from Facebook Chat via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, browser-extension, crossrider

I am writing a JavaScript-based browser extension (using CrossRider.com).

How can I use JavaScript to logout from Facebook Chat. I want to force the user to go "offline" automatically via code.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that the correct way to end a user's FB session is to create an FB app and use the [FB.logout](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/) SDK method. If this is not possible, then you can try deleting the FB session cookie which should terminate the login.